# Underscript min x latex

Tags: math-mode

does any of you know how i can underscript in latex.

I want to write min and then a x under, like on the image.

Thanks!! <3[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/277964)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context, so a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) would have been useful.

If this should be math, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[\min_x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `x` is not a variable you can use `\min_{\mathrm{x}}` or even `\min_{\text{x}}`, depending on the expected result. See [the `amsmath` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for more information about `\text`.

For other use cases, see also `\limits` and `\nolimits` in [the `amsmath` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).

Comment: It's not necessary to load the `mathtools` package to run `\min`.

Comment: @Mico I know, but IMHO new users cannot learn early enough to use at least `amsmath` or even better `mathtools` and I also bring up `\text` in my answer, which needs at least `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve your formatting goal depends on whether `\min` occurs in inline-math mode or in display-math mode. In the former case, it's necessary to write `\min\limits_{\mathbf{x}}`. In the latter case, you can just write `\min_{\mathbf{x}}`.

[image: mod]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\min\limits_{\mathbf{x}}$ \quad $\displaystyle\min_{\mathbf{x}}$
\end{document}
```